# When is a second milah required

Tags: brit-milah

When is a second bris milah required?

Is it possible to require a second milah after masturbating for some time?

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I don't think that this question is a duplicate of the one suggested, which deals with, does the act of masturbation cause any changes vis-a-vis what a PERSON may and may not do? This question asks whether some type of physical rectification needs to be done to the Milah ITSELF, due to its defilement by masturbation ("hatafas dam bris?). The answers given there, are irrelevant to the question being posed here.

Answer (score 3):

The effect of the sin of masturbation on the Milah, is a **spiritual** one, and doesn't affect the **physical** status of the Milah.

Therefore, if a person was properly circumcised after birth (from the 8th day and on), and no physical changes occurred in the interim; then there is no further obligation regarding the actual Milah, even if the person did sinful actions with this organ.

However a person who has stumbled in the sin of masturbation should make all efforts to do Teshuva and repent for this sin. If he does so, then Hashem will surely forgive him.

The problem is, that Teshuva in this area can sometimes be difficult, since it’s difficult for a person to wean themselves from their addiction to the sexual gratification that comes with masturbation. However there are different online resources to help those who seek spiritual purity.

One of them is: “[Guard Your Eyes](https://guardyoureyes.com/)”.

Wishing you much success on your spiritual journey!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Have you heard of the term "mosheich beorlo"? Do you have any details of it?

Comment: "Mosheich beorlo" literally means tugging at the foreskin (or the small amount of it that remains after being circumcised). The main discussion of this issue; is not in context of masturbation, rather regarding the prohibition of re-growing or restoring the foreskin. If someone PERMANENTLY stretched out their skin (not just temporarily played around with it), or grafted on new skin, and now they look uncircumcised, they might need to have this undone with a second “cut”. If you want to discuss this further, privately, I can send you an email address.

Comment: Please do send me your email adress, thanks!

Comment: I have seen. Thank you from the bottom of my heart.

Comment: Hi TS, I hope that all is well with you., and that you're winning your battles. Looking forward to hearing from you. IR